# Size of array 'exceeded', but array is small

Tags: c++, arrays, class, compiler-errors, undefined

Edit: looks like the problem was overuse of #includes creating circles. I made sure to only include those needed and it solved the first two errors.

However, I still get "multiple default constructors specified" for both BUtton and Elevator

It has two of each error, but both of the pair point at the same location, the ending }; of the class.

Edit: Second error also solved. I removed the empty Class::Class(); that wasn't being used.

====================================
I'm getting an error "error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes.

The first line in my class definition that makes an array of objects gives this error, regardless of size of class or array. "Elevator elevators[1];" will give the error even though the Elevator object is only about 70 bytes. However, it will not stop on an array of ints, strings, etc, even if they are very large.

I am honestly not sure what to include for code for this.

```
class Passenger;
class Simulation{ 
   int test[10000];<-- no error
   std::queues<int> q[10];<--- no error
   Elevator e[1];<--- size error, but size of one Elevator is only 70 bytes
}
```

Below that error it also says "Simulation:elevators uses undefined class Elevator", but I 
do have that initialized above. I also have passenger.h #included. I was originally using vectors, but they were actually causing more problems, and I don't really need them since the size is constant.

Further testing showed one of my objects (Report) doesn't give the error, but it is larger with several vectors involved.

Edit ( Actually it gives the errors for both Elevator and Button regardless of where in the code they are.

Edit: Adding full elevator define as per request:

```
class Elevator{
private:
   int floor;
   int floorGoal;
   int answering;
   int floorIdle;
   bool goingUp;
   int mode;
   int nextMode;
   int nextModeTime;
   int numPassengers;
   static const int maxPassengers = 8;
   int passengers[maxPassengers];
   static const int moveTime = 15;
   static const int boardTime = 3;
   static const int leaveTime = 3;
   static const int delayTime = 10;
public:
   Elevator();
   Elevator(int Floor = 1);
   ~Elevator();
   bool IsFull() const;
   bool IsEmpty() const;
   void Update(int timeElapsed, int i, PassengerGenerator& gen, Report& r, Button b[], Elevator e[], std::queue<int> q[]);
   friend class Simulation;
};
```

Also including button, since it has the same errors but is much simpler

```
class Button{
private:
   int answered;
   bool pressed;
   bool up;
public:
   Button();
   Button(int Floor = 1, bool Up = true);
   ~Button();
   inline bool IsCalling() const{ return pressed && answered == -1;}
   friend class Elevator;
   friend class Simulation;
};
```

While I was doing this I noticed another error farther down the list. It says 'multiple default constructors specified' for both Elevator and Button. However, I confirmed that both only have only one construtor with no parameters, defined for both as format   Class::Class(){}

Comment: Elevator type definition please.

Comment: What platform and compiler?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem actually is the use of an undefined class. Please include the definition of Elevator, as well as where it is located relative to the classs Simulation

Comment: Did you `#include "Elevator.hpp"`?

Comment: The problem is probably the 'undefined class Elevator'; it is odd that that message doesn't appear first.

Comment: `std:queues`?  Without actual code that exhibits the problem, it is practically impossible to help you solve your problem.  Post a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem, and post the exact compilation errors reported by the compiler.

Comment: It's C++ VS2010. I included the other class definitions now.
Yes, I #included the .h file

Comment: The std::queues is not important. The errors happen regardless of if it is included.

Answer (score 2):

You must define the type `Elevator` before you can use it to declare the data member `e`.  You have declared the type, but you have failed to define it.

The first error is somewhat misleading, but the second error is quite clear:

```
error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes
error C2079: 'Simulation::e' uses undefined class 'Elevator'
```

Comment: It is above this class with both an #include "elevator.h" and a class elevator;   What more does it need to be defined?

Comment: You probably have circular dependencies among your headers then.  Does Elevator.h #include anything that directly or indirectly #includes the source file in which your Simulation class is defined?

Comment: I stripped unneeded includes and it fixed the first two errors, so thanks.
I still get the 'multiple default constructors' for both though